# C++ equivalent syntax for a C# generic delegate, and usage with lambdas

Tags: c#, c++, templates, generics

In C# I can do this:

```
delegate void myFunctionDelegate<T>(T arg);
```

In C++, I understand that I need to use an alias to a template for a function pointer, but the syntax is so bizaare that all of the examples I find just confuse me more.

The following is wrong; how can I correct it?

```
template<typename T>
using myFunctionDelegate = void (*)(T arg);
```

I want to use it like so:

```
template<class T> class Foo
{
    ...
    void someOtherFunction(myFunctionDelegate callback)
    {
        ...
        callback(someValue);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
myClassInstance.someOtherFunction([&](T arg) {
    // do something with the callback argument
});
```

Comment: Depending on the context, you might not even take the explicit type and instead have a template parameter that represents any type that allows you to call it with that argument. Even with the explicit type, a function pointer is a poor choice. Your example will not work because a capturing lambda cannot be converted to a function pointer. An easy alternative is `std::function`.

Comment: Thanks for your input, though as you may have guessed from my example above, I don't understand this area of C++ well enough to deduce the solution from your comment. I'd need a more detailed answer...

Comment: As a quick example, the C++ STL uses another template parameter. `std::find_if` would be declared similar to `template<typename Iter, typename UnaryPredicate> Iter find_if(Iter first, Iter last, UnaryPredicate pred)`. Inside the body, you'd simply see something like `if (pred(*first))`. Rather than requiring a certain predicate function type, you can give it any and it will fail to compile if the call doesn't work.

Comment: Rather than using the comments area, why not write an answer? If it solves my problem, I can mark it as correct and others may benefit from it.

Comment: I guess I can always delete it if it doesn't.

Comment: Or don't even do that. Often I get value from SO answers that were not the one marked as correct. Your answer may fall into that category too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have almost works syntactically; the use of `myFunctionDelegate` simply needs a type argument:

```
void someOtherFunction(myFunctionDelegate<T> callback)
                                         ^^^
```

And the alias parameter names are optional if you aren't getting any particular benefit from them:

```
template<typename T>
using myFunctionDelegate = void(*)(T);
```

However, there is a larger problem: function pointers don't handle state. The lambda used in your sample call uses state by the capturing it does. Thus, a capturing lambda cannot be converted to a function pointer. When it's so handy to pass in such a lambda, function arguments should support that.

There are two common ways of doing so. The first is to forget about forcing a specific return and parameter type. Instead, let the caller pass any object (lambda, function pointer, functor, the result of `std::bind`) that can be called the way your function calls it:

```
template<typename Callable>
void someOtherFunction(Callable callback) {
    ...
    callback(someValue);
}
```

If the call doesn't work, the code will fail to compile<sup>1</sup> (with an error that unfortunately isn't too helpful, but the future [Concepts](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4377.pdf) additions can easily help there).

On the other hand, you might want to explicitly specify the function type. C++ has a general-purpose type to store any callable object (see the above list). That type is `std::function`. It's a bit more heavyweight than a simple template parameter, but useful when you need it.

```
template<typename T>
using myFunctionDelegate = std::function<void(T)>;

void someOtherFunction(const myFunctionDelegate<T> &callback) {...}
```

---

<sub>[1]: This isn't always true (see SFINAE), but it probably will be as far as you're concerned.</sub>

Comment: Actually, eggs on my face - you actually can have parameter names in the *type-id*, though it's rather pointless... I misremembered a particular quote in the standard about *type-id*s being syntatically a declaration with the name omitted - it's just the name of the thing being declared, not all names.

Comment: @T.C., I kind of assumed you couldn't, especially after your comment, but OK. I suppose it's just as handy as the optional ones in function forward declarations for documentation, though.

Comment: @NathanRidley, Glad to hear it. I always feel the need to make these longer than they have to be if they're answers :/

Answer (score 2):

`std::function<void(T)> myFunctionDelegate` is the (very) rough equivalent of `delegate void myFunctionDelegate<T>(T arg)`

`std::function<void(T)>` follows value semantics (it behaves more like an `int` than a C# object reference) which makes things different.

A lambda closure (`[](T t){/*code*/}`) whose lifetime (or copies of it) outlives the local scope should not use `&` based capture.  Instead use `=` based capture (which may require extra work).  If the code you are calling does not store a copy of the delegate beyond the lifetime of the call, `[&]` is optimal.  In C++ the lifetime of data is something you need concern yourself with.

This is not intended as a full tutorial on how lambdas and `std::function` work, but just to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, that is handy to know.